# code formatting with Angular material in Visual studio 2012

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012

i have been using visual studio 2012 and ctrl+k+d is working fine for HTML indentation

but as i use Angular material html tag i m not able to indent code / Ctrl+K+D doesn't work too.

for example

```
<md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-raised md-primary" aria-label="Open some menu">    
                      <md-icon   class="material-icons">account_circle</md-icon>
                        <span md-menu-origin>Salman Zafar</span> 
               </md-button>
```

Comment: if you absolutely *need* this functionality, you should use the `data-` variants instead.  for example, `data-md-button`

Comment: i have tried that too but it didnt worked:(

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having same issue in Visual Studio Code